# Python: How can I fetch passages containing given keywords from a text file

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, string-matching, information-retrieval

I am trying to implement a factoid based question answering system. So far I have retrieved candidate text documents which may contain answers.
But now I am stuck where I have to extract right passages from the documents based on the keywords provided.

I have briefly studied approaches like LCC and InsightSoft, but cannot figure out how to move forward.

Consider that I have a document containing many paragraphs(passages).I want to rank these paragraphs based on certain keywords.

**Example:**

Keywords- *leopard*, *lion*

Para 1: "..no sentence about *leopard* or *leopard*..""

Para 2:"..few sentences about *lion*.."

Para 3:"..sentences about both *lion* and *leopard*.."

**Goal**: To rank(or fetch) Para 2 and Para 3

How can I implement(program) the same? 
And is there a way to rank these passages based on the tag provided to the keywords by a POS tagger?

Any code or implementation of existing algorithms will be appreciated. Please be elaborate while explaining as I'm not an expert in Python.

Comment: We have no clue what your data look like or what you want to extract. To make help possible, provide more information.

Comment: Given that you already have "text file" in the title, "files with text" doesn't help in the slightest. Your question is akin to asking for a good set of technical interview questions without specifying the position, field, or industry.

Comment: Your patience is appreciated, I hope the changes make point clearer.

Comment: So you want to tokenize your paragraphs (represent each paragraph as a list of words) and do the same with the keywords, then output all of the paragraphs that contain one or more keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013941/relevance-of-document-to-multiple-keywords/29380252#29380252) question on stack overflow, it's along the same lines.

You're going to want to tokenise your paragraphs and input, your output could simply be every passage that contains a word in your query, or the results could ranked using a [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model).